# Eye implant/surgery for AR/VR?

Tags: biology, trans-humanism

In the distant future with advanced medical technology, if a person gets commercially-available eye "surgery" to facilitate AR/VR entertainment or technical work (like a Heads-Up-Display but without the glasses), what form would it be?

Grafting electronics to the retina? An artificial intraocular lens? Or maybe an electronic signal that hacks the optic nerve? What would be practical and realistic – biologically speaking?

I'm looking for something along the idea of LASIK or cataract surgery, so not replacing the whole eyeball with a William Gibsonesque cyborg laser thing, but unobtrusive. When it is not receiving a signal it should not interfere with normal vision.

Comment: I would close this question as it's seems you didn't even do a bit of research. Distant future? AR lens? Here's an article form 2009 https://spectrum.ieee.org/biomedical/bionics/augmented-reality-in-a-contact-lens/0 and article on wearable from 2016 https://www.wareable.com/wearable-tech/best-smart-contact-lens

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY you are free to cast a VTC with that very reason

Comment: *"In the distant future..."*. Could you 25 years ago have foreseen the smartphone? 50 years ago, could you have fore seen the Internet? So what you ask "What form would it be"... really, who is to say? And then in the second part of your post you flip the question around and start saying "This is what I **want** it to be". That is a whole different question. In the first part you are asking for options. Then you say "I only want **this particular option**". Make up your mind what you are actually asking: are you looking for all possible options, or a way to **not** have certain options?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Lack of research is a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: @Frostfyre yet the user is free to cast a VTC if they want to. Especially if they start a comment with 'I would close this question' - don't just say it, do it! If people disagree it will stay open.

Answer (score 5):

## We can't know for sure, we can know what is tested now

And for now, it looks like **brain implants** are one way to go.

For example [this article](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/608844/blind-patients-to-test-bionic-eye-brain-implants/):

> The company, Second Sight, is testing whether an array of electrodes placed on the surface of the brain can return limited vision to people who have gone partially or completely blind. For decades, scientists have been trying to develop brain implants to give sight back to the blind but have had limited success.

On the other hand, **retina implants** are [apparently also working](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/may/03/eye-implants-restore-sight-blind):

> The operation begins with a power supply being implanted under the skin behind the ear. Surgeons then implant the 3mm-by-3mm chip through a small flap in the delicate retina at the back of the eye.

Personally I believe that people will accept eye implants easier than opening their skulls and operating directly on the brain, but both are feasible.

Pros of eye implant:

- Simplicity and safety of surgery
- Easier to reverse

Cons of eye implant:

- Can impair original seeing

Pros of brain implant:

- Seeing independent from original eyes, potentially "third eye" effect (not tested on subjects with functioning sight, so we can't tell for sure)
- Bigger area, so potentially better resolution with the same size of single electrode.

Cons of brain implant:

- Dangerous surgery
- Leaves potential gate of infection to the brain.

Answer (score 4):

**No, thank you.**

Anything implanted has multiple issues: infection, obsolescence, power source replacement/rupture. One of Greg Egan's early novels, Quarantine, discussed the security issues around having brain implants (they get hacked, to show you advertising, continuously).

If I can't secure my phone OR keep its OS up-to-date for 36 months after purchase, why would I have it surgically implanted? I get a rash from wearing a watch. Into my brain? Nooo.

I could imagine things to help with eye/hand/retina tracking (a targeting tattoo?), but optical tracking works better every day-- why bother?

Answer (score 3):

You can have something relatively simple as a mean to stimulate retina sensors (either with an overlay or directly at optic nerve level).

Main problem with an in-ocular device is to keep track of [saccadic movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade) and update the image accordingly with high precision. This is less of a problem with extra-ocular devices which need to track the much slower and predictable head movement.

Direct Optic nerve stimulation would need a calibration phase to match nerve with sensor, but would probably be more reliable not requiring "moving parts".

Current hardware would be able to handle throughput (eye resolution is "just" ~1Mpixel, but **not** on a square matrix, our "pixels" are arranged in logarithmic spiral), but they would need "some" miniaturization.